# Getting Dates from Week Numbers - Year Starts from March - Week 1 = March 1st week - PHP

Tags: php, date, week-number

I am trying to write a custom function for getting dates from week numbers but the requirement is that the week numbers are custom i.e. **the week1 starts from 1st Week of March and the First Day of each week is Friday**
I trying to do this in PHP.

Your help or advice would be really helpful for writing this function.
I have gone through some of functions here but doesnt actually fit my requirement.

Thanking You

Comment: Can you give sample input and sample output of your function?

Comment: This is a function Reference of this is Stackoverflow itself
$week_number = 1;
$year = 2013;
for($day=1; $day<=7; $day++)
{
    echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($year."W".$week_number.$day))."\n";
}
But here it takes the standard weeks and as said my week starts in march

Comment: So week #1 can actually be less than 7 days? e.g. if 1st March falls on a Thursday, it will be a 1-day week?

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for your reply. Actually its bit complicated than that maybe for me :)
For E.G.
Month = March = 1st Month of Year
1st week starts from 1st March
So, Week#1 = 1st March to 7th March.
The Catch
If 1st March = Thursday then 2nd March will be the start as the Start Date should always fall on Friday

Comment: So week 1 starts on the first Friday on or after 1st March?

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes the week #1 starts on Friday of March and then so on. Like each week start day is Friday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might give you a starting point:

```
$year = 2012;
$startDate = new \DateTime($year . '-03-01');
$startDate->modify('Friday');
echo $startDate->format('Y-m-d') , PHP_EOL;
$endDate = new \DateTime($year+1 . '-03-01');
$endDate->modify('Friday');
echo $endDate->format('Y-m-d') , PHP_EOL;

$interval = new \DateInterval('P1W');
$weekPeriod = new \DatePeriod ($startDate, $interval, $endDate);

foreach ($weekPeriod as $key => $weekDate) {
   echo 'Week #' , $key + 1 , ' starts on ';
   echo $weekDate->format('Y-m-d') , PHP_EOL;
}
```

You can use this to build an array, that you can then use as a lookup

Comment: Thanks Mark. I will go through it and update you. Thanks for your quick help

Comment: Yes you are right its very helpful to start off for what I want to achieve. Thanks a lot again. :)